# How to use multilayer perceptron and make predictions given a skew-distributed feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm fairly new to deep learning and Keras, and this problem has bothered me for weeks. Hope I can get some hints from here.

**Features**:

I simulated two variables, each has 10k samples and follow a standard normal distribution: `A ~ Norm(0, 1)`; `B ~ Norm(0, 1)`.

**Labels**

And I derived two labels from the simulated variables: `y1 = A * B`; `y2 = A / B`.

**Model**

Input dimension: 2

Hidden layers: 4 dense layers, all of them were 32 neurons wide

Output layers: a dense layer with 1 neuron

Activation functions: `ReLU` for all the activation functions

Compiler: `'MSE'` as the loss function, `'Adam'` as the optimizer with learning rate at 1e-05

**Tasks**

Finally, I set up three tasks for MLP to learn:
(1) Use A, B to predict y1;
(2) Use A, B to predict y2;
(3) Use A, 1/B to predict y2

**Validation**

Use `'validation_split = 0.2'` to verify the model

**Results and Inference**

It can reach `MSE` below 1 easily for both training and validation set after 10~15 epochs in task 1. However, I'll always get a very high loss like 30k+ on training loss for the other two tasks.

[update] I also evaluated the results by Pearson correlation coefficient, which returned ~0.7 for task 1 and <0.01 for task 2 and 3.

It's weird to me since the ideas of multiplication(`y1`) and division(`y2`) are mathematically the same. So I then tried to look into the distribution of 1/B, and I found that it has extremely long tails at each side. I surpose it might be the source of difficulty but couldn't figure any strategy for it. I also tried to normalize 1/B before the training but got no luck on it.

Any advice or comment is welcome. Can't find discussion on this either on web or books, really want to make some progress on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

y2 values have a much different distribution from y1 values, specifically, it will have values with much larger absolute values.  This means that comparing the loss directly isn't really fair.

It's kinda like estimating the mass of a person vs. estimating the mass of a planet, and being upset that you're off by millions of pounds.

For an illustration, try calculating the loss on all three problems, but with an estimator that only ever guesses 0.0.  I suspect that problem 1 will have much lower loss than the other two.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right, simply comparing MSE can't serve as a fair standard. However, I also evaluated the results by Pearson correlation coefficient, which returned ~0.7 for task 1 and <0.01 for task 2 and 3.